# Difference between __c and __r?

Tags: relationships

I read this article for [difference between __r and __c](https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Establish_Business_Logic). But I still can't understand how is **Hiring_Manager__c.Email** will be different from **Hiring_Manager__r.Email**

[image]

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`__r` represents a custom relationship. There are two uses for `__r`. We use it when we query a custom relationship from child to parent, or from parent to child.

For example, if you have two custom objects, called `Service__c` and `Service_Line__c`, where the Service Line has a field that references a Service as its parent, you can query from child to parent, or parent to child.

The child to parent relationship query looks like this:

```
SELECT Id, Service__c, Service__r.Name FROM Service_Line__c
```

While the parent to child relationship looks like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Service_Lines__r) FROM Service__c
```

To access parent and children records in Apex Code, you'd use the same syntax:

```
Service_Line__c line = [select ... from service_line__c where ...];
if(line.service__r.name == 'Master Service') {
    // Do something
}

Service__c service = [select ... from service__c where ...];
for(Service_Line__c line:service.Service_Lines__r) {
    // Do something
}
```

Each mechanism has a specific purpose depending on your intent.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. That was a simple and detailed explanation. But can you tell me why is there need for two SELECTS in   parent to child relationship?

Comment: Sounds like you have a bit of reading to do before you will understand as this fully as this is foundational type knowledge. But, you need the second select (subquery) to return the children of the parent using the relationship as the key. There is a lot of documentation related to subqueries.

Comment: @MnZ It's called a sub-query, of which there are two types: the former is as I showed here, to query children from a parent. The latter lets you query a set of records based on another set of records, such as: `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE HasOptedOutOfEmail = TRUE)`. It's of limited usage, but when it is useful, it is very useful indeed.

Comment: I now understand and can write parent to child and child to parent query. Thanks @sfdcfox and Eric

Comment: Watching question after 9 years and makes me smile that the answer is helping so many budding developers!

Answer (score 9):

`__c` is for Custom objects For example: Custom_Object__c . It is used for reference custom object in Apex or visualforce page, formula field etc internally. Used as suffix.

`__r` is for Custom objects **reference** For example: Custom_Object__r . It is used for reference custom object relation ship name in Apex or visualforce page, formula field etc. Used as suffix.

In image you have posted: Hiring_Mansger__r is relationship name.

Native object don't require __c as suffix.

Comment: This is the simplest answer that provides the best description for what I needed to know. When using `__r`, I'm assuming that's essentially doing a SQL `JOIN` under-the-hood, so I should use `__c` where I can correct?

Comment: You should us `__r` when accessing child records. `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Custom_Object_Child__r) FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE Parent_Custom_Object__c IN: (SELECT Id, Name FROM Parent_Custom_Object__c WHERE Name ='Test'))`.

Comment: I'm using the GraphQL API, so I want to improve the query performance. If `__c` is on the object itself, then GraphQL won't be making a `JOIN` behind the scenes. That's what was hoping to find out :). Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to think about this is that the relationship name might not be the same as the object name. For example, if you have a custom object Car_Market_User__c, you might have an object Car__c, with a Buyer__r and Seller__r. Typically, however, the name is the same, which is why it's auto generated based on the model name as Car_Market_User__r.

Answer (score 1):

`__r` is used in case of accessing relationship fields. Like in your case Hiring Manager is the Parent of Position object. So if you want to access parent (Hiring Manager) object fields from child object(Position) then you must use lookupfieldName__r.fieldAPIname `Hiring_Manager__r.Email`

Comment: When do we need to access relationship fields? I mean in what condition? Can't we do it by r"__c"?

Answer (score 1):

Just happen to come across this post and thought of adding my commentary in hope to further help MnZ. I would just try to clarify a bit more to what sdfcfox and others have already explained.

__c refers directly to a custom object whereas __r refers to a reference (a relationship) between two objects such as the parent-child object relationship or child-parent object relationship in order to help you 'get' or 'navigate' to the parent from a child or vice versa.

An Example

Let us say you have a Class__c parent object (one) with a child relationship to Student__c objects (many). Now, you want to get the names of the students, and for each student, the name of the class associated with that student. You can use __r relationship to get to Class__c when querying Student__c.

In psuedo code, you may say:

Get names of students and the class name associated with each student's name

You could rephrase this in sdfc lingo like this:

Use Student__c object to get the names of the students and use student-to-class / child-to-parent relationship (Student__c.Class__r) to get the associated name of the class

Using __c and __r , the above will translate into something like:

```
Select Student__c.Name, Class__r.Name from Student__c;
```

Another Example - getting to students from a class using __r

Get class name from `Class__c` and the names of all students associated with the class using `Class_c.Students__r`

```
Select Class__c.Name, (many students for a given class using Class__c.Students__r) from Class__c
```

or

```
Select Class__c.Name, (Select Name from Students__r) from Class__c;
```

Comment: thank u very much; yes it d0es make sense :)