# quey a field i through a reference custom object field

Tags: apex, query

I have 3 custom ojects. Partner-Partnership-Referente_Int. On Partnership I have a lookup on Referente_Int and one on Partner. Now I need to query 2 fields of Referente_int from Partnership.
I write this query:

```
select id,Partner__c,Referente_int__c.Cognome__c from Partnership__c where Partner__c='0015800000Ewo4zAAB'
```

But that throw the error:
"Didn't understand relationship  'Referente_int__c' in field path.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28708/difference-between-c-and-r answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the parent record value from child record You should use the **__r** relationship. try this code.

```
SELECT id,Partner__c,Referente_int__r.Cognome__c FROM Partnership__c WHERE Partner__c='0015800000Ewo4zAAB'
```