# testing class problem - how to compare name of the parent object in the assert?

Tags: soql, unit-test, salesforce-id

Thanks for comments. I have problem with tests for the below class, I would like to compare name of the parent element Child2 with string Child1 which should be the result, but I got all the time Id number against its Name. What can I do?

```
public static List<Region__c> RegionTestFunction(String rname){
        List<Region__c> listReg = [SELECT Parent__r.Name FROM Region__c WHERE Name =: rname];
            System.debug(listReg);
            System.debug(listReg.get(0).Parent__c);
            return  listReg;
    }

@testSetup
    static void setupTestData() {
        List<Region__c> testList = new List<Region__c>();

        List<Region__c> testList2 = new List<Region__c>();
        Region__c Parent1 = new Region__c(Name='Parent01');
        insert Parent1;
        testList2.add(Parent1);
        Region__c Child1 = new Region__c(Name='Child1');
            Child1.Parent__c = Parent1.Id;
        insert Child1;
        testList2.add(Child1);
        Region__c Child2 = new Region__c(Name='Child2');
            Child2.Parent__c = Child1.Id;
        insert Child2;
        testList2.add(Child2);
        System.debug(Child2.Parent__c);

    }
    static testMethod void myUnitTestRegionTestFunction() {

        Test.startTest();
        List<Region__c> testList = RegionQueries.RegionTestFunction('Child2');

        Test.stopTest();

        System.debug(testList);
        System.debug(testList.get(0));

        System.assertEquals('Child1', testList.get(0).Name, 'Parent__c contains correct name');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify the problem you are having. Your grammar is difficult to understand. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Your query is returning relationship field `Parent__r.Name` but you are trying to assert against `Region__c.Name` field : `testList.get(0).Name`

Comment: my function returns list with Parent__r.Name  so I tried to get its first element

Answer (score 1):

`__c` is the field that contains an Id. `__r` is an Object that contains a reference to parent SObject record, or an SObject List that contains a list of child SObject records.

```
System.debug(listReg.get(0).Parent__c);
```

Simply prints out the Id of the record the field references, while:

```
System.debug(listReg.get(0).Parent__r.Name);
```

Would print out the parent record's Name field.

See also [Difference between __c and __r?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28708).

For your assertion that's failing, you're not referencing the correct field, presuming I'm following your logic correctly. It should be:

```
   System.assertEquals('Child1', testList.get(0).Parent__r.Name, 'Parent__r contains correct name');
```