# Visualforce page at parent with table records from custom child

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, table, parent-to-child

I have a parent custom object called Game__c and a child custom object called Player__c.).

The child Player__c has 4 fields: Name(String), Phone__c(Number), isHealthy__c(boolean), and Game__c(lookup).

im trying to create a Visualforce page presented in each Game record the related child records arranged in a table(fields in table are name,phone,isHealthy). i have problem with access to the records of child.

**code**

```
 <apex:page standardController="Game__c">
     <apex:pageBlock title="Hello!">
       You are viewing the {!Game__c.name} Game.
      </apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlock title="Players">
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Game__c.Player__c}" var="p">
          <apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.phone__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.isHealthy__c}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

To access a custom child relationship, you need to use `__r` suffix instead of `__c`.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Game__c.Player__r}" var="p">
```

You can read more about this syntax in one of my [older answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31064/2984).