# Join a custom object

Tags: soql, developer

I've read a few posts on custom object joins but none seem to help. I have custom object `SBQQ__Quote__c` and `Contact`. Inside `SBQQ__Quote__c`, I need to take `Billing_Contact_c__c` look up the `Email` from `Contact` for that `Id`. I'm using workbench.developerforce.com if it matters.

## SBQQ__Quote__c

[image]

## Contact

[image]

I have tried the following

### Attempt 1

```
SELECT Acc_Name__c, Contact__r.Email
FROM SBQQ__Quote__c
```

The error:

```
INVALID_FIELD:
SELECT Acc_Name__c, Contact__r.Email
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:21
Didn't understand relationship 'Contact__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

### Attempt 2

```
SELECT a.Acc_Name__c, b.Email
FROM SBQQ__Quote__c a, Contact b 
WHERE b.Id = a. Billing_Contact_c__c
```

The error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY:
SBQQ__Quote__c a, Contact b WHERE b.Id = a. Billing_Contact_c__c
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:76
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code
```

### Attempt 3

```
SELECT Acc_Name__c, (SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = Billing_Contact_c__c) 
FROM SBQQ__Quote__c
```

The error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY:
(SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = Billing_Contact_c__c) FROM SBQQ__Quote__c
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:58
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code
```

### Attempt 4

```
SELECT SBQQ__Quote__c.Acc_Name__c, Contact.Email 
FROM SBQQ__Quote__c, Contact 
WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c.Billing_Contact_c__c = Contact.ID
```

The error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY:
SBQQ__Quote__c.Billing_Contact_c__c = Contact.ID;
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:122
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code
```

Comment: Is `Billing_Contact_c__c` defined in the object schema as a relationship? Take a look at [Relationship Queries with Custom Objects](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/create-relationship-queries-with-custom-objects) Trailhead tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Relationship Name` as your field. Typically, the relationship name simply replaces `__c` with `__r`.

```
SELECT Billing_Contact_c__r.Email FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE  ...
```

**[Recommended reading](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/28708/2995)**