# I have an Accounts with multiple related Contacts. How can I retrieve only one Contact for each Account?

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I have an Accounts with multiple related Contacts. My requirement is to retrieve one contact record for each account. If one Account has multiple Contact, I just want to retrieve one Contact record.

I tried the code below

```
String query,temp;
List<Contact> con = [Select Id, Account from Contact Order By Id];
Set<Contact> conIds = new Set<Contact>();
for(Contact conCheck:con){
   if(temp != conCheck.Account){
     conIds.add(conCheck.Account);
   }
}
query = 'Select Id from Contact where Id IN conIds';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement, is there nothing to indicate which contact would be preferred? If you don't specify any additional criteria, you're going to get whatever contact Salesforce happens to see first. This could be the first contact ever created, but it might be something else entirely. Without additional information to search on, the contact you get will be almost random.

Comment: I have a checklist field that needs to be edited on the Contact to be 'true' and it will serve as an indicator for something else. I need to get one related Contact record from the Account and edit its field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from the Account level and query downwards:

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Contacts LIMIT 1) FROM Account 
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)];
```

You now have a list of all accounts that have at least one contact, and will have a child list consisting of just one Contact. You can even use this with a query locator directly:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator(
[SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1) FROM Account 
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How about same scenario but I want to query the Custom Relationship example Contact related to a Custom Object?

Comment: @newbieApexLWCDev Nothing much changes, just using `__c` and `__r` for custom object names and relationships, respectively. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31064/2984).

Comment: I tried this code but I'm having some issue. SELECT Contact.Id, (SELECT Block__c.Id, Block__c.ContactId, Block__c.VariableChecker FROM Block__r Limit 1) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT Block__c.ContactId FROM Block__r)

Comment: @newbieApexLWCDev `select id, (select id, contact__c, variablechecker__c from blocks__r limit 1) from contact where id in (select contact__c from block__c)` should probably work. It takes some time to get used to when each should be used.